# iText Error: Nullable object must have a value

Tags: itext, itext7

Using iText7 PDFSweep, C# implementation.

During redaction, iText appears to throw "System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value" exception depending on the regular expression used for redaction.

For example, the code below throws exception:

```
String regex = @"(\s?7-\d\d\d\d)";
CompositeCleanupStrategy strategy = new CompositeCleanupStrategy();
strategy.Add(new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy(regex).SetRedactionColor(ColorConstants.RED));
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(srcFile), new PdfWriter(outFile));
PdfAutoSweep autoSweep = new PdfAutoSweep(strategy);
autoSweep.CleanUp(pdf);  
pdf.Close();
```

However, things work OK if I remove the "\s?" from the regex.
This confuses me in 2 regards

1. Adding \s? to the regex should only make the regex getting more matches
2. Notwithstanding the above, why would an exception be thrown depending on the result of regex match?

Edit (Adding stack trace):

```
Error Msg = Nullable object must have a value.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy.GetResultantLocations()
   at iText.PdfCleanup.Autosweep.CompositeCleanupStrategy.GetResultantLocations()
   at iText.PdfCleanup.Autosweep.PdfAutoSweep.GetPdfCleanUpLocations(PdfDocument doc)
   at iText.PdfCleanup.Autosweep.PdfAutoSweep.CleanUp(PdfDocument pdfDocument)
   at pdf_redactor.Program.Main(String[] args) in G:\prj\pdf_redactor\pdf_redactor\Program.cs:line 77
```

Comment: The exception seems to only throw when I try to put whitespace at the beginning of the regex.  What I'm trying to do is redact certain pattern (such as 7-1234), but only if its preceded by a whitespace)

Comment: i have the same problem, i think this is bug in library